# Adding show/hide to my div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I got 4 div tags, with id's - `content1`; `content2`; `content3` and `content4`.
at start, `content1` is only shown, and all other 3 contents are invisible, and I got menu with links, `#content1`, `#content2`, `#content3`, `#content4`.
So I need to create, when somebody clicks for example on `content3` link, current content will hide and `content3` content will show up, same to all other contents.

My question - I know how to make show/hide with one element, but I haven't created anything with 2 or more elements, so maybe you could help me create it?

Comment: This is basically a menu with tabs. You should be able to find plenty of posts here about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your content divs a class, say "content", it is easy to select them as a group and hide them. Similarly, if you give your menu links a class you can assign a click handler to all of them at once. So:

```
<a class="menu" href="#content1">Content 1</a>
<div class="content" id="content1">Some content here</div>
<!-- and so forth for your other links and divs -->

<script>
   $(function() {
       $("a.menu").click(function() {
          $("div.content").hide();
          $(this.href).show();
          return false;
       });
   });
</script>
```

Note that you don't really need to wrap the code in a document.ready handler if the script block appears after the elements in question, but I've done so here for completeness.

I realise the above may not correspond to your html markup, but since you didn't actually provide your html markup I had to guess...

If there's anything in this answer that you don't understand I suggest you read through some jQuery tutorials, such as [this one from the jQuery website](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery); a tutorial is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer...

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Sandy (sorry, I overwrote your edit without even noticing it, but I agree with it).

Comment: Hello,
hmm, it made everything go away, and nothing is coming up. Here is my code - http://paste.php.lv/d81d71785c365e3f08904958c0babdd4?lang=php

Comment: @user1114408 - it may be that the browser is returning the full path from this.href rather than just the bit in the attribute. Try putting alert(this.href) to test. Or you could try changing that line to $($(this).attr("href")).show(); and see if that helps. Note also that your last two menu items had the same href.

Comment: God bless you :)! It worked, Merry christmas and thanks 1000 times ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Per @Robin's suggestion, check this out:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/