# Hide/show div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding show/hide to my div tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625031/adding-show-hide-to-my-div-tags)

the hide/show div tags is not working for me, maybe you could help me fix it? When I click link, it hides all div tags, but doesn't show new one.
http://paste.php.lv/37ed543091129e148004a3e5335904fb?lang=php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>STANDBY Countdown Script</title>
<script src="script/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/jquery.jcountdown1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jcountdown-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/standby-style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#time").countdown({
        date: "January 31, 2013", /* Counting to a date */
        offset: 1,
        hoursOnly: false,
        leadingZero: true
    });

  $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.val('');
      input.removeClass('placeholder');
    }
  }).blur(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
      input.addClass('placeholder');
      input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
  }).blur();    

});
</script>

<script>
   $(function() {
       $("a.menu").click(function() {
          $("div.content").hide();
          $(this.href).show();
          return false;
       });
   });
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header-menu">
    <a class="menu" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#">Information</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="content" id="#home">
    <img src="images/christmas-hat.png" style="margin-top: -50px; margin-right: -50px;float: right;" /> 
    <div class="content-top">
      <h1>Welcome to STANDBY Test Version 1</h1>
      <p class="description">Currently we are on Test Version 1. For more information, please leave your email and name below. We will contact you back in one working day!</p>
    </div>
        <div class="content-middle">
          <h2>UNDER CONSTRUCTION:</h2>
      <p id="time" class="time"></p>
      <div class="time-text">
      <span class="d">Days</span>
      <span class="h">Hours</span>
      <span class="m">Minutes</span>
      <span class="s">Seconds</span>
      </div> 
    </div>    
      <div class="content-bottom">
        <table> 
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td><?php 
              if(isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit'] == 'Send') {
                if($_GET['email'] != '')
                {
                  $email = $_GET['email'];
                  if(!preg_match('/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$/', $email)) {
                    ?>
                    <span class="submit">Email must be valid!</span>
                    <?php  
                  }
                  else {
                  $nl="\n";
                  $headers = "From: ".$email." <".$email.">".$nl;
                        $headers .= "Message-ID: <".time()."-".$email.">".$nl;
                        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$nl;
                        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$nl;
                        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; boundary=\"".md5(time())."\"".$nl.$nl;          
                  $to = 'patissthemes@gmail.com';
                  $subject = 'I want to learn more about your upcoming project';
                  $content = 'Hello, I would like to learn more about your project! <br /> Please reply to '.$email.'';
                  mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
                    ?>
                    <span class="submit" style="Color: green; border-color: green;">Your email was sent!</span>
                    <?php           
                  }
                }
                else {
                  ?>
                  <span class="submit">All fields must be filled!</span>
                  <?php        
                }
              }
            ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <div class="form">
        <form method="get" action="">
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Type your email here" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="icons">       
          <td><a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/ico_facebook.png" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/ico_twitter.png" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="http://linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/ico_linkedin.png" /></a></td>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-shadow"></div>  
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="aboutus">
    <img src="images/christmas-hat.png" style="margin-top: -50px; margin-right: -50px;float: right;" /> 
    da
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show the resulting html, with javascript, instead, that would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Post code, not a link to some random website.

Comment: where is the html that you are trying to show and hide? you are only showing html. Try with a simple example first. Have you had a look at: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Tomas -  $("div.content").hide();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should lead you down the right path: http://jsfiddle.net/m7vhv/

## HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-menu">
        <a class="menu" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a class="menu" href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
        <a class="menu" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        <a class="menu" href="#">Information</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content" id="home">
    home
</div>

<div class="content" id="aboutus">
    about us
</div>
```

## JS

```
$("a.menu").click(function() {
    $("div.content").hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    return false;
});
```